# Надо ли ставить тире

Tags: пунктуация

Надо ли ставить тире после слова **ЕАЭС** в предложении:

*ЕЭК рекомендует членам Высшего Евразийского экономического совета — главам государств ЕАЭС принять решение о начале переговоров по заключению соответствующего соглашения.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что в этом предложении необходимы два тире:
*ЕЭК рекомендует членам Высшего Евразийского экономического совета — главам государств ЕАЭС — принять решение о начале переговоров по заключению соответствующего соглашения.*

Сюда подходит правило: при обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире — для выделения (с двух сторон) *приложения, носящего характер пояснения или уточнения.*
[**Знаки препинания при обособленных приложениях**](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg61.php)

*ЕЭК **рекомендует членам** Высшего Евразийского экономического совета... **принять решение** о начале переговоров по заключению соответствующего соглашения*, но не всем членам, а ***только*** главам государств ЕАЭС.

Comment: Скорее всего, это одни и те же лица:  членами ВЕЭС как раз и являются  главы государств.

Comment: Трудно определить по отдельному предложению:  уж я эти аббревиатуры ( в одном высказывании) извертела со всех сторон — их три!

Comment: Мне  кажется, что это просто стандартная форма для указания двух должностей одних и тех же лиц, она часто встречается.  Вставка же  вряд ли применяется в сообщениях такого рода.

Answer (score 2):

ЕЭК рекомендует **членам** Высшего Евразийского экономического совета — **главам государств** ЕАЭС принять решение о начале переговоров по заключению соответствующего соглашения.

**Тире ставится.** Это тема обособления приложений с помощью тире (выбор одного или двух тире).
[§ 19. Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)

Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:

2) если приложение выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение: На совещании министров иностранных дел **стран** — **членов Организации американских государств** выступил министр иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.).

**Из Википедии**

В [Высший Евразийский экономический совет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%95%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82) входят главы государств стран-членов Евразийского экономического союза (ЕЭК).

Таким образом,  в ВЕЭС **нет других членов, кроме глав государств**, поэтому отсутствует  значение уточнения и  **ставится одно тире.**